# Looking for an alternative approach to Find the minimum value of the function $f(x, y)=4 x^{2}+9 y^{2}-12 x-12 y+14$ is

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, problem-solving

The minimum value of the function $f(x, y)=4 x^{2}+9 y^{2}-12 x-12 y+14$ is

*My work*
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text f(x, y) &=4 x^{2}+9 y^{2}-12 x-12 y+14 \\
&=\left(4 x^{2}-12 x+9\right)+\left(9 y^{2}-12 y+4\right)+1 \\
&=(2 x-3)^{2}+(3 y-2)^{2}+1 \geq 1
\end{aligned}
$$
So, minimum value of $\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{y})$ is 1

My question is How can it be done by calculus?

Comment: Your work is fine. You can also use derivatives to find the minimum value. But your approach is trickier and it is done by calculus.

Comment: *callculus*  speaking to *Integral calculus* about *calculus*. Nice combination ! But, if I may ask, what is *calculus* ?

Comment: @Integralcalculus. Thank you !

Comment: I never would have thought of this approach. Nice work

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work out the partial derivatives of the function, namely
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 8x - 12, \qquad 
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 18y - 12 $$
Now you set both derivatives equal to zero to find the stationary points: $8x - 12 = 0$ and $18x - 12 = 0$ and you get a single point with co-ordinates $(3/2,2/3)$. It remains to prove that it is a minimum. This can be done with the Hessian matrix, i.e. by finding the second order partial derivatives:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 8, \qquad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = 0, \qquad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 18.
$$
The hessian is therefore
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 0 \\
0 & 18 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since both eigenvalues are positive (the matrix is positive), the point is a minimum.

Finally,
$$
f\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right) = 1.
$$

Comment: The sign of the det isn't useful. But rather, you should say that the Hessian is positive definite to conclud. e

Answer (score 1):

If a function attains a minimum at point $(x_0, y_0)$ then both partial derivatives at this point are zero.
In this case, derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$
f(x, y)=8 x -12
$$
and the derivative with respect to $y$ is
$$
f(x, y)= 18y - 12
$$
This means that $0 = 8x - 12 \Rightarrow x = 3/2 $ and $0 = 18 y - 12 \Rightarrow y =2/3$, which coincides with your result.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, changing $18y-12$ to $18y-9$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is nice, but to do it with calculus set $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=8x-12=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=18y-12=0$ to find $(x,y)=(\frac32,\frac23)$, and then evaluate $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x, y)=4 x^{2}+9 y^{2}-12 x-12 y+14$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=8x-12$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=18y-12$$
Set the partial derivatives equal to $0$; so $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and $y=\frac{2}{3}$
$$f\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right)=1$$